# node.js: Recovering from database connection close

Tags: mongodb, node.js

Lets say my db wrapper code looks like this:

```
DB.open('localhost', port, function(err, db){
  exports.withDatabase = function(callback) {
    callback(db);
  }
});
```

As this is a separate module, the DB is open only once when first required. This takes care of not having to open the connection on every access, also module require is synchronous, so database is not connected more than once. But if the connection goes down and comes back later, how do i get this code to reconnect.

Comment: https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/database.md states that there is an `auto_reconnect` option. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Tomolak: I have not tried it. Thank you, i will try it. But my question is more about the design pattern - how do i design when i have a resource like DB connection. If i do not block on reconnect/open, there is a chance that a connection state can get into an invalid state.

Comment: @Suresh: That chance is always there, even with blocking I/O. Someone just needs to trip over a cable. For non-blocking I/O just use the events that are provided. *PS: Unless this question is **not** about mongodb, please put the tags back in.*

Answer (score 3):

[The docs](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/database.md) state that you can either use the `auto_reconnect` option when you create the server connection or react to the "close" event that fires when the DB connection is lost:

```
DB.on("close", function(error){
  // ...
});
```